# Datagram Channel Sockets not writing Java

Tags: java, android, sockets, channel, datagram

Simply said, I'm able to receive data from the connected socket, until about 10 seconds after it starts. The solution to fix this is, to send data to the 'client'(an ARDrone) to keep the data stream going, otherwise it will stop sending data to the phone. However, my current code for some reason only writes data to the client (the ARDrone) on first connect and never after. I need it to keep sending data to the ARDrone even after the socket is communicating.

I've tried moving around the `channel.register()` calls, but nothing I've done seems to send data to the ARDrone, as I need.

Creating the connection:

```
channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.configureBlocking(false);
channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(video_port));
channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(drone_addr, video_port));

selector = Selector.open();
channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
```

Here is the current send/receive data function.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        ByteBuffer inbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFSIZE);
        done = false;
        while (!done) {
            selector.select();
        if (done) {
            disconnect();
            break;
        }
        Set readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
            if (key.isWritable()) {
                byte[] trigger_bytes = { 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
                ByteBuffer trigger_buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(trigger_bytes.length);
                trigger_buf.put(trigger_bytes);
                trigger_buf.flip();
                channel.write(trigger_buf);
                channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                inbuf.clear();
                int len = channel.read(inbuf);

                if (len > 0) {
                    inbuf.flip();
                    final BufferedVideoImage vi = new BufferedVideoImage();;
                    vi.addImageStream(inbuf);
                    drone.videoFrameReceived(0, 0, vi.getWidth(), vi.getHeight(), vi.getJavaPixelData(), 0, vi.getWidth());
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        drone.changeToErrorState(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the socket blocking somewhere in the while loop?

Comment: @ethrbunny I don't see how it could, especially if I use channel.configureBlocking(false); when I start the channel. It might be helpful if I add that code to the main post, which I will do right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you corrupt your event interest on the first write with this line:

```
channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

[Per documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectableChannel.html#register%28java.nio.channels.Selector,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29), this resets it to `OP_READ` only.

#### Edit 0:

Per your comment - yes, I think you should remove that line entirely, ***and*** do not treat read and write cases as alternatives. In general a socket could be readable and writable at the same time. So what's happening now is that the write case prevents the read case since UDP socket is *always* writable (versus TCP that buffers outgoing data).

So my suggestion is to not include `OP_WRITE` into that event set at all, but handle writing in some other fashion, say on a timer, or after each read, or whatever makes sense to your app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that is true, however, changing it to register both read and write seems to make the drone not give any data at all after the first connection.

Should I just remove that line entirely?

Comment: I just found out that by moving the line, the start of the connection won't be sent. When the first bytes are written to the socket (what should happen if its writable) it triggers the Drone to send data. So removing it would make it never send data. And removing just the OP_WRITE line would make the Drone so it just disconnects immediately, as I just found out.

Comment: Send your first packet before registering with selector.

Comment: It already is sent before registering. Or do you mean the register that's in the upper code block that has both the read/write?

Comment: I do not understand. What is the wait exactly? Won't everything up in the top execute almost immediately? Or does one pause until connect?

Comment: `selector.select();` is the wait.

Comment: Great it working. However, it seems to display the video feed like normal. Then cut out for a few seconds. Then go back and receive video for a little bit. So is there any way I can reduce this time? I would assume it has to do with how long its waiting at selector.select() but I'm not sure. My Log says that the Android phone's Garbage Collector is working, which means that its recycling something, but its not Logging that its receiving the actual data (video).

Comment: Try not to allocate (`new`) anything in the I/O loop. That's probably what causes GC to kick in. Have all buffers pre-allocated and re-use them.

Comment: Well, its got to be more than that. The Garbage collector is recycling an average of 800k every couple couple hundred milliseconds, which is what I'm estimating the amount of space an image from the video would require.

Comment: This goes into video processing. I'm not a specialist here, but AFAIK you can preallocate two frames, have one being read by the I/O loop, while having the other rendered by the UI, and keep flipping them (lookup "double-buffering"). I think this is all the help I can offer (sorry, cannot really go to chat.)

Comment: But still, the problem doesn't seem to be having to do with the image processing/displaying. I don't know what data is being recycled by the garbage collector, but I suspected that it was the images. However, my Log still isn't showing that its receiving data during those few seconds. That is all I am worried about at this point. Making it so there is no delay between video feeds.

Comment: your answer was accepted since its partially working and because you put in so much work. Thank you very much.